# How to Get Specific data from Database SQLITE in a Text View?

Tags: android, sqlite

Guys at this time i want to ask HOW TO GET SPECIFIC DATA FROM DATABASE SQLITE THEN SHOW IT IN A TEXTVIEW in SEARCH ACTIVITY

```
public ArrayList<Sma> getPoint(String name)
{
    ArrayList <Sma> point = new ArrayList<Sma>(); 

    String selectQuery = "SELECT latitude_sma, longtitude_sma FROM sma WHERE nama_sma ='" + name + "'"; >> FROM HERE I JUST WANT TO SHOW latitude_sma, and longtitude_sma IN A TEXTVIEW
    open();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Sma sekolah = new Sma();
            sekolah.setLatitude(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(latitude_sma)));
            sekolah.setLongitude(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(longtitude_sma)));
            point.add(sekolah);
        } 
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return point;
```

PLEASE HELP ME!, thx B4 :)

Comment: what is wrong query not working?

Comment: no, i think the query is okay, but how to show in a textView? cause i don't know how..

Comment: You need to call this function in a activity. This returns a list. You can display the data from list based on index

Comment: can u give me some example, display a data from a list based on index, cause i don't know how :D

Comment: i just did post a code snippet. should give an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by specific data.

You need to call the function that returns a list and display data in textview based on index position

In Activity

```
Database db = new Database(this);
ArrayList<Sma> list = db.getPoint("your name");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(list.get(0).getLatitude().toString());
```

Comment: okey, i want to ask, list.get(0) > is this the index from database? cause when i tried, it's error IndexOutOfBoundsExecption. :D

Comment: @ndr_sd that is not the index from the database. List in index based. index starts from 0. so if you get a exception check if the list is populated

Comment: hei, i'm sorry do u know how to put this tv.setText(list.get(0).getLatitude().toString()); into a double variable?

Comment: @ndr_sd double variable?  `double var=  Double.parseDouble(list.get(0).getLatitude().toString())`

Comment: okayyyy, once again i said thanks to u, and thank u it's really helping ;D